# Loading map of mapbox on a function call

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, mapbox

I am working with the rendering of Mapbox in Angular framework. Right now the issue what am facing is that I cannot load the map in the browser.
I have defined a function where I've given all the required to load the map and I am calling the function from an HTML `div` container after validating a condition. The control goes into the function but the error is that it is not identifying the container property of the map.

My HTML code:

`<div id="map" style="margin-top: 370px;" *ngIf="result;then loadMap()">`

my script:

```
loadMap(){
this.map=new Map({

  container:document.getElementById('map') ,//'map'

  style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',

  center: { lng: -102.380979, lat: 35.877742 },

  zoom: 9,

  pitch: 20,

  attributionControl: false
  });

  this.map.addControl(
    new NavigationControl({
      showZoom: true,
      showCompass: true
    }),
    'bottom-right'
  );
}
```

The error that I am facing:

`Error: Invalid type: 'container must be a String or HTMLElement.`

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B15TM.png)

Also, is it really possible to load map with a function call or am I just wasting my time here?

Answer (score 1):

This is what i've been doing.I cannot give upon ngAfterViewInit because it is required for initialization purpose of the DOM.

```
   export class DashboardComponent implements OnChanges,OnDestroy,AfterViewInit {

 @Input() searchResults:SidenavComponent;

  private map: Map;

  constructor(){  }


  ngOnChanges(changes:SimpleChanges){

     if(!changes.searchResults){
       console.log("Inside if");
       console.log(changes.searchResults)
       this.ngAfterViewInit()
     }

    // const preValue=changes['searchResults'].previousValue;
    // const curValue=changes['searchResults'].currentValue;
    // if(preValue!=curValue){
    //   this.ngAfterViewInit()
    // }

}

   ngAfterViewInit(){

     this.map=new Map(
       {

         container:document.getElementById('map'),

         style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',

         center: { lng: -102.380979, lat: 35.877742 },

         zoom: 9,

         pitch: 20,

         attributionControl: false
       });
       this.map.addControl(

         new NavigationControl({

           showZoom: true,

           showCompass: true
         }),

         'top-right'

       );

   }

      ngOnDestroy(){
     this.map.remove();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The container property of the map`<div id="map">` is available once the statement in `*ngIf` returns true / has completed. This is not the case as long as your `loadMap()` has not finished. Therefore you cannot identify the container.

--> The container needs to exist before you make the function call.

Comment: Okay,that is true.Now i have updated my code  since i thought ngIf would make things complicated.So am using ngOnChanges and ngAfterViewInit lifecycle.With this,the map is loading only for the first time of search event.When the next search is happening,the map isnt loading while i get all other data related to the search but not the map.I dont know how to proceed with this

Comment: Can you share the code for what you have just described?